# 助詞｢も｣の意味を教えてください

Tags: grammar

「こういうこと**も**、歳をとったらできなくなるだろうなあ」という文中の助詞｢も｣の意味を教えてください。

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What research have you put into it?  What do you think the sentence means as a whole?  What is the context?  This question will not likely be answered until you edit your question with some more information.

Comment: Actually, I left my account logged in to my tutor's computer, and she was the one to post the above question in an effort to answer a question I had posed to her about what nuance the 助詞「も」 added to the sentence. The sentence she posted above differs from the sentence that prompted my question to her in our lessons. As such, I cannot at this time edit this question to make it more inline with question creation guidelines. I will try to revisit this tomorrow, as I meet with her tonight.

Comment: So which language do you want this question to be answered in English or Japanese?

Answer (score 2):

By using も, the speaker may be implying the activity is *not the only* thing he is going to miss. There are a lot of activities out there that are gradually getting away from you as you grow old.

At least he is not thinking it to be a special case, for which は should be used instead.